# VBA Repeatable Function on button click

Tags: excel, vba

I'm presently working on a worksheet to monitor and manage drivers for my company. I have a button running some VBA code to remove duplicates. It works fantastically one time. However, if I remove some of the data and add more data to the set, the button no longer works. I would like to have the button repeat its function every time I click it. Opening a new instance of the worksheet every time I want to add more drivers to be monitored is just not feasible. Any and all help is appreciated, and my skills are very basic in this area, so as thorough of an explanation/instruction the better (and patience). Thanks ahead of time.

Below I have added the code I have for the Remove Duplicates button and a screenshot of what my sheet looks like.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim rg As Range

With Worksheets("Driver Info Tool")
        lgLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rgData = .Range("A1:D" & lgLastRow)
    End With
With rgData
        .Sort Key1:=.Columns(4), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: "the button no longer works" ...how so? What doesn't work?

Comment: If you click the button, it removes the duplicates, then you add new information in Column A in addition to the data remaining, and if you click the button again, it does nothing. The duplicates remain and there are no changes to the form. 

I appreciate you taking the time to take a look and asking, I should've been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove Duplicates Based on a Single Column

- The following is still a basic code but with a few tweaks. BTW, you haven't declared either variable. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of each module, to never let it happen again.
- There are a few ways to do this. If it doesn't work, let me know I'll try something else.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim rg As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Driver Info Tool")
        If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
        Set rg = .Range("A1:D" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    
    With rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        .Sort Key1:=.Columns(4), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    End With
    
End Sub
```